# MATLAB adding structs to array

Tags: arrays, matlab

My struct "design" has a field "couplings", which is an array of structs:

```
design.couplings = struct.empty;
```

And later in the code I am trying to do the following: each element in `design.couplings` is a struct with a `name` (a string) and `values` (an array of doubles). If `design.couplings` element with a given `name` already exists, I only add an element to `design.couplings(j).value` array. If it doesn't, an element with that name is added to the end of the table.

```
keySet = {'Coupling energy (injector)', 'Coupling energy (injector2)'};
valueSet = [ coupling_energy_iu,         coupling_energy_iu2 ];

coups = containers.Map(keySet, valueSet);

for i=1:length(keySet)
    found = 0;

    if isempty(design.couplings) == 0
        for j=1:length(design.couplings)
            if design.couplings(j).name == keySet{i};
                found = 1;
                design.couplings(j).value(end+1) = values(coups, coups(keySet{i}));
                break;
            end
        end
    end
    if found == 0
        design.couplings(end+1) = struct('name', keySet{i}, 'value', []);
        %design.couplings(end+1) = struct('name', keySet{i}, 'value', [coups(keySet{i})]);
    end

end
```

Execution of this code ends with an error:

```
Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures.

Error in selfSimp1>loadSelfSimp (line 259)
        design.couplings(end+1) = struct('name', keySet{i}, 'value', []);
```

It seems I can't simply add another structure to the array. Why?

Comment: When you do 'design.couplings(j).value(end+1)', what is the type of your element ? Array of array ?  The problem is because you try to insert a struct with cell array (KeySet) and with array and into your design.couplings isn't cell array/array anymore. It's my assumption.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau But the code doesn't even get to the line that you are referring to (because when it runs for the first time, `if isempty(design.couplings) == 0` is true). Also, the struct that I am inserting doesn't include a cell array, it's just a value from a cell array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initialising an empty struct with no fields, but you want an empty struct with the fields 'name' and 'key'

```
design.couplings=struct('name',{},'value',{})
```

instead of

```
design.couplings = struct.empty;
```